# Shortcut to replace arrow, out from brackets

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

When you open brackets, parenthesis, and so on, IPython Notebook automatically closes it, leaving the cursor inside, ready to type the arguments. After typing, is there any shortcut out of the brackets other than the arrow key? (It would be nice to use TAB or some other key closer than the right arrow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use autoclose brackets in Jupyter notebook? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777958/how-to-use-autoclose-brackets-in-jupyter-notebook)