# How to use autoclose brackets in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

This may sound like a silly question, but how do I make use of the autoclose brackets in Jupyter notebook? For example, when I type

```
print(
```

Jupyter notebook auto-closes the brakets

```
print()
```

and places the cursor inside. Then I could type the argument, say

```
print(1 + 1)
```

now my cursor is between the second `1` and the right bracket `)`. What is the key to navigate to the right of `)`?

Of course I can press <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> or even <kbd>)</kbd> to achieve this, but it does not seem to save time, which is the purpose of the brackets autoclose I suppose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ')' will get you to the right of the paren. The purpose is not for simple cases like above but more complex cases, every time you open a bracket it puts the corresponding close to help you keep track of things - e.g. `l = [(i.split( ...` has autoclosed  `))]`.

Comment: @AChampion Since the question is unanswered for a (long) while, what about you posting that as an answer? (although since apparently op asks "what's the purpose of... it can be opinion-based; in that case the question can be closed, but the answer can be posted to the older question that I linked here)

Comment: The inefficient implementation of [pair closing](https://codemirror.net/addon/edit/closebrackets.js) (quote, parenthesis, bracket) in [Code Mirror](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) is a significant wasting of time and a source of parsing errors when you need to add these elements afterwards (closing element silently discarded, pair of quotes inserted). Just consider [not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22843891/774575) and type the closing element manually. Disappointing feature of a otherwise fantastic tool.

Answer (score 10):

We can do that from the jupyter console, try it.

[image]